# Use span on MarkerWithLabel with mouseover/mouseout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a Google Maps map and have some `MarkerWithLabels` there. When the user hovers over the marker I want to show some additional information about the marker. E.g.

`Not hovering => 10`
`Hovering => 10 people`

However, the bottom text should be in another color, so I thought I'd be best using a span to change the text colors of the two texts. I've done this

```
googleMaps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    var mouseoverImg = new googleMaps.MarkerImage('/images/pin_xl.png', null, null, null, new googleMaps.Size(53, 72));
    this.setIcon(mouseoverImg);
    this.set('labelClass' ,'' );
    this.set('labelContent', "<p class='startContinentCountryBigTop'>" + poiObject.count + "</p><br><p class='startContinentCountryBigBot'>" + cities + "</p>");
    this.set('labelAnchor', new googleMaps.Point(20, 65));
});
googleMaps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    this.setIcon(markerImage);
    this.set('labelContent', poiObject.count);
    this.set('labelAnchor', new google.maps.Point(11, 42.5));
    this.set('labelClass' ,'startContinentCountrySmall' );
});
```

The problem is, that with the span, as soon as I mouseover the marker the mouseout function is also triggered. So the Marker get's repeatidly smaller/bigger. When I remove the span and am just using the text it works without problems, but the bottom text needs to have a different color and a different text-size. What are some workarounds to this problem?

These are my css classes

```
span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.startContinentCountrySmall {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #bdc3c7;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.startContinentCountryBigTop {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #bdc3c7;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
.startContinentCountryBigBot {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f69d00;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Some additional information: It seems to be the problem, that you can't add HTML Elements to a `MarkerWithLabel`. Even when I created a Node like this

```
var newDiv          = document.createElement("span");
newDiv.className    = "startContinentCountryBigTop";
newDiv.innerHTML    = poiObject.count;
```

it doesn't work. The problem occurs when you hover over the text on the marker that has the HTML tags wrapped

I hope you understand the problem. The mouseover and mouseout listener are fired at the same time all the time as soon as I start using span for the text on the marker. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to figure this one out?

Comment: Hi. I made it "dirty". The normal text had the class "example" and I styled it there. For the text that would come after I didn't write it direct into the marker. I created a class "example::after" and wrote the content directly in css. Temporary workaround but works.